# Running http-webserver and ws-socket-server on same port

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, deployment, network-protocols

The [Heroku tutorial on creating/deploying a web- and a socketserver](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets) has the following piece of code setting up those servers:

```
const server = express()
//...
const wss = new SocketServer({ server });
```

In other words, one server runs for example at http://localhost:8080 and the other one at ws://localhost:8080. So the http server is referencing the socket server by:

```
var HOST = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws')
var ws = new WebSocket(HOST);
//...
```

Now while I did not use the exactly same code, running both servers on the same address and port with the only difference being the protocol (http and ws) makes the websocket-server unreachable:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/.
```

Changing the port to anything else fixes the problem. Why is that? And how should I implement my application, considering that Heroku recommends using static ports only as a fallback like

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

instead?